# Could not understand, why the logic in updateQuestionTrue/ updateQuestionFalse is making an error

Tags: java

Working on a one tutorial. Decided to implement the method logic to decrement or increment the array index. Somehow, it is still going outside the size of my array. Why is it happening?

```
mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.show();

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        mTextView.setText(mQuestionBank[mIndex].getQuestionId());
        updateQuestionTrue();

    }
});

mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nope...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.show();

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        mTextView.setText(mQuestionBank[mIndex].getQuestionId());
        updateQuestionFalse();

    }
});
```

Here is the wrong logic method. Could you explain me, why it is going outside the size of my array?

```
private void updateQuestionTrue() {
    mIndex++;
    if(mIndex == mQuestionBank.length) {
            mIndex = 0;
    }
}

private int updateQuestionFalse() {
    mIndex--;
    if(mIndex == 0) {
      mQuestionBank[0].getQuestionId();
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: What is `updateQuestionFalse` supposed to do? It's not stopping `mIndex` from going below 0..

Comment: perhaps once mIndex == 0 you stop decreasing the value...

Comment: it should stop mIndex to go below 0, but I just cannot get it..  The logic is then mIndex == 0, it should be initialised with 0 and return first question from an array

Comment: also I would recommend the possibility of user error and have your if checks be >= mQuestionBank.length and <= 0 incase you decremented the index too far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ensure that your index will always be in a valid range based on the length of your array. You can try the following

```
private void updateQuestionTrue() {
    if(mIndex + 1 >= mQuestionBank.length) {
        mIndex = 0;
    }
    else
        mIndex++;
}

private int updateQuestionFalse() {
    if(mIndex - 1 <= 0) {
      //mIndex = mQuestionBank.length - 1; //too loop back around
      mIndex = 0; //or to keep the index at 0 once you are as far back as possible
    }
    else
        mIndex--;

    return mIndex;
}
```

You can also use my personal favorite, ternary operator

```
private void updateQuestionTrue() {
    mIndex = mIndex + 1 >= mQuestionBank.length ? 0 : ++mIndex;
}

private int updateQuestionFalse() {
    return (mIndex = mIndex - 1 <= 0 ? 0 : --mIndex);
}
```

Comment: It helped me not to go outside my array.length. Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome, good luck with future coding endeavors! @AlexanderGolovinov

Answer (score 0):

Just as `updateQuestionTrue()` sets `mIndex` to 0 when it would otherwise equal `mQuestionBank.length`, `updateQuestionFalse()` should set `mIndex` to `mQuestionBank.length - 1` when it would otherwise be less than 0.  In this way, it will loop to the end when you go back before the start, just as it loops to the start when you go off the end.

I'm not sure what `mQuestionBank[0].getQuestionId();` does in your code, though.